# Need to sort a numpy array based on column value, but value is present in String format

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am a newbie in python and need to extract info from a csv file containing terrorism data.

I need to extract top 5 cities in India, having maximum casualities, where Casuality = Killed(given in CSV) + Wounded(given in CSV).
City column is also given in the CSV file.

Output format should be like below in descending order of casuality

> city_1 casualty_1  city_2 casualty_2  city_3 casualty_3  city_4
>   casualty_4  city_5 casualty_5

Link to CSV- https://ninjasdatascienceprod.s3.amazonaws.com/3571/terrorismData.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIGEP3IQJKTNSRVMQ&Expires=1554719430&Signature=7uYCQ6pAb1xxPJhI%2FAfYeedUcdA%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DterrorismData.csv

```
import numpy as np
import csv
file_obj=open("terrorismData.csv",encoding="utf8")
file_data=csv.DictReader(file_obj,skipinitialspace=True)
country=[]
killed=[]
wounded=[]
city=[]
final=[]

#Making lists
for row in file_data:
    if row['Country']=='India':
        country.append(row['Country'])
        killed.append(row['Killed'])
        wounded.append(row['Wounded'])
        city.append(row['City'])
        final.append([row['City'],row['Killed'],row['Wounded']])


#Making numpy arrays out of lists
np_month=np.array(country)
np_killed=np.array(killed)
np_wounded=np.array(wounded)
np_city=np.array(city)
np_final=np.array(final)


#Fixing blank values in final arr
for i in range(len(np_final)):
    for j in range(len(np_final[0])):
        if np_final[i][j]=='':
            np_final[i][j]='0.0'


#Counting casualities(killed+wounded) and storing in 1st column of final array
for i in range(len(np_final)):
    np_final[i,1]=float(np_final[i,1])+float(np_final[i,2])

#Descending sort on casualities column
np_final=np_final[np_final[:,1].argsort()[::-1]]
```

I expect np_final to get sorted on column casualities , but it's not happening because type(casualities) is coming as 'String'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using int() or float() to transform your string

Answer (score 0):

I would offer for you to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). It would be easier for you to manipulate date.
Read everything to DataFrame. It should read numbers into number formats.

If you must to use np, while reading data, you could simply cast your values to float or integer and everything should work, if there are no other bugs.
Something like this:

```
for row in file_data:
if row['Country']=='India':
    country.append(row['Country'])
    killed.append(int(row['Killed']))
    wounded.append(int(row['Wounded']))
    city.append(row['City'])
    final.append([row['City'],row['Killed'],row['Wounded']])
```

Comment: I tried casting where i calculated casualities, but somehow final array is again completely in String format, also if i try to convert whole final into float, it gives error because City names can't be converted into float.